# serializing jython objects in java

Tags: java, python, jython

I followed the instructions [here](http://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonMonthly/Articles/October2006/3) for using python objects in Java. However, in Java, I need to serialize a object which contains the python object. The java object itself is serializable.  So, may I know how do I do it?

I got the error message

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.python.proxies.MorphyWrapper$MorphyWrap$1
```

when I attempt to do so.

Comment: What version of Jython are you using?

Comment: OK that version has fixes for serialisation bugs so I imagine that what you're facing is a genuine case of not be able to serialise an object that doesn't implement Serialisable (this would be true of Java objects as well).  Don't know anything further than that I'm afraid.